# For-loop, map and forEach Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a deck of 52 cards. I can create it easily with double for-loop but it has O(n2) complexity. So I was trying to play with map() and forEach() array methods but things are complex with them needing to return stuffs. Here is my code below.

```js
(function deckCreate() {
  var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
  var suits = ["clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"];
  var newDeck = values.map(function(xValue) {
    suits.forEach(function(xSuit) {
      return [xSuit,xValue];
    });
  });
  return newDeck;
}());
```

It gives an array of length 13 all undefined inside. I tried swapping forEach() before map() just incase but the result was the same.

The issue I found while console.log() inside those functions was that the elements were not being mapped to each other but were printed all separately. What could be the issue be?

Comment: Could i just ask is your goal to increase speed of script execution?

Comment: You're getting `undefined` because `.forEach` doesn't return anything. Change that to `.map` and put a `return` at the beginning of that line and it should work correctly. As far as performance I'd be surprised if this took more than 1ms.

Comment: @sinisake nah just trying to learn new ways of doing rather than nested for-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your `map` function, so the implicit return value is `undefined`, hence your array of 13 `undefined` values.

`suits.forEach` needs to be `return suits.map`. This will give you an array of 13 elements, where each element is an array of four elements, where each element of the *inner* array is a two element `[suit, value]` array. You can then `reduce` the top-level array into the 52 element array you're after:

```
var newDeck = values.map(function(xValue) {
  return suits.map(function(xSuit) {
    return [xSuit,xValue];
  });
}).reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b) });
```

Comment: What is purpose of `.reduce()` call?

Comment: @guest271314 As I said: The result of `map(map(...))` is a a nested array of `13(4(2))` elements. The question was how to produce a 52 element array of suit/number pairs. Reduce concatenates the 13*4 arrays into a single 52 element array. You could also pass the top-level array to `Array.prototype.concat.apply` and achieve the same results.

Comment: Where does text of Question describe expected result being "a 52 element array of suit/number pairs"?

Comment: @guest271314  "I am trying to create a deck of 52 cards".

Comment: @meagar you are right. i did initially with double map and got similar 13 length array with each array element having [values[0],[suits]]. i need to look at reduce() method. thanks :)

Comment: @meagar "I am trying to create a deck of 52 cards" is not equal to "a 52 element array of suit/number pairs".

Comment: @Jamie Can you clarify expected result at text of Question?

Comment: @guest271314 the result i was expecting was somewhat like [ [val,suit],[val,suit]...] similar as to what i'd get if i did double for-loop

Comment: @guest271314 check my new update `var deck = new Deck(); deck.iterate(fn);`

Comment: @Jamie Consider including the description of expected result within textual body of Question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having trouble is that you aren't returning from your outer `.map()` callback. Even if you did, though, `[].forEach` always returns `undefined`, regardless of what happens inside its callback.

So, since you're using `forEach` to iterate the inner array, you get an array of 13 undefineds from `map`.

What you should be using is `.map()` all the way down and return every step of the way:

```js
const first = [1, 2, 3];
const second = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const mapped = first.map(function(digit) {
  return second.map(function(letter) {
    return [digit, letter];
    });
  });

console.log(mapped);
```

Seeing how you're clearly trying to learn and improve yourself, I'll leave you to adjust this example to your specific case.

P.S. If you want a flattened array, have a look at `[].reduce()` and `[].concat()`.

Comment: _"`return [xSuit,xValue]`"_ Given pattern at Question should `first` and `second` be reversed at `.map()` calls?

Comment: @Madara Uchiha thanks senpai for the answer. i will check out reduce() method now

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to simplify it.

We know that there are just 4 suits, so it's enough to get list by suit name:

```js
function createDeck() {
  var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
  var deck = {"clubs": values.slice(), "diamonds": values.slice(), "hearts": values.slice(), "spades": values.slice()};
  return deck;
}

var deck = createDeck();

console.log('CLUBS:', deck.clubs);
console.log('DIAMONDS:', deck.diamonds);
console.log('HEARTS:', deck.hearts);
console.log('SPADES:', deck.spades);
```

P.S. in my case I'll create a class that makes generation, iteration and etc stuff to easily use it.

```js
function Deck() {
  var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
  var suits = ['clubs', 'diamonds', 'spades', 'hearts'];
  
  this.getSuits = function() {return suits.splice();}
  this.getValues = function() {return values.splice();}
  
  var asObject;
  this.asObject = function() {
    if(asObject) return asObject;
    
    asObject = {};
    suits.map(function(suit) {
      asObject[suit] = values.slice();
    });
    return asObject;
  };
  
  var asArray;
  this.asArray = function() {
    if(asArray) return asArray;
    asArray = [];
    
    suits.map(function(suit) {
      values.map(function(value) {
        asArray.push([suit, value]);
      });
    });
    return asArray;
  }
  
  this.iterate = function(fn) {
    this.asArray().map(fn);  
  }
}

var deck = new Deck();

deck.iterate(function(card) {
  console.log('CARD: ', card[0], card[1]);             
});

console.log(deck.asObject());
console.log(deck.asArray());
```

Comment: How is `newDeck` accessed outside of IIFE?

Comment: oh, I understand, sec, modifying

Comment: @guest271314 check now (;

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `for` loop. Use `suits[Math.floor(i / 13)]` to get the right suit, and use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) `%` to get the card number for each suit:

```js
function deckCreate() {
  var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
  var suits = ["clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"];
  var newDeck = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    newDeck.push([suits[Math.floor(i / 13)], values[i % 13]]);
  }

  return newDeck;
}

var result = deckCreate();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you are right. but it won't help if i want to use face-values like J,Q,K etc initially (i can change it later tho) :)

Comment: @Jamie - changed the answer to work with the original `values` array.